# Regular Expression Match to Extract Command

Tags: javascript, regex, command, pattern-matching, match

String: `Z123xy;Z123od33;Z123od343;Z251od541;`
Regex: `Z.*?od.*?;`
Required Output: `[Z123od33;  Z123od343;  Z251od541;]`
But Current Output : `[Z123xy;Z123od33;  Z123od343;  Z251od541;]`

[image]

I know why its happening that way but don't know how to solve this. Any one could help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go for

```
Z[^;]*?od[^;]*?;
# require a Z
# anything not a ; lazily
# od
# anything not a ; lazily again
# followed by a ;
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mO3vPv/1) or split on the `;` and analyze the parts later separately.

Comment: could you please help if I want to extract based on id as well. I mean extract all command have od and 123 like [Z123od343  Z123od33] should be output

Comment: @WasimA.: Please post another question here.